# show first_name, last_name and email in profile serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Profile model which after user signs up has to update their profile. For that i have designed two serializer, one UserSerializer to show the list of users and another ProfileSerializer which has lots of fields for user to add in their profile. The user not only gets to update their profile like height, weight, age, location, body_type etc but also should get to update first_name, last_name, email from the profile.

Here is my UserSerializer and ProfileSerializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(source="user", view_name="user_profile")
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    token = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'user', 'current_location', 'permanent_location', 'dob',
                    'about_me', 'gender_status', 'create_profile_for', 'marital_status',
                    'height', 'weight', 'body_type', 'complexion',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', None)
        last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name', None)
        user_inst_fields = {}
        if first_name:
            user_inst_fields['first_name'] = first_name
        if last_name:
            user_inst_fields['last_name'] = last_name
        if user_inst_fields:
            User.objects.update_or_create(id=instance.user.id, defaults=user_inst_fields)
        profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(token=instance.token, defaults=validated_data)
        print('profile', profile, created)
        return profile

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'profile', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

I could not show the fields of first_name, last_name and username for user to update them along with their profile.

You can see the screenshot, no first_name, last_name and username is shown

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show the `first_name` , `last_name` and `username` in `ProfileSerializer` using `source` keyword argument in a `CharField` for first_name and last_name and username.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(source="user", view_name="user_profile")
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    token = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source = "user.first_name")
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source = "user.last_name")
    username = serializers.CharField(source = "user.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'user', 'current_location', 'permanent_location', 'dob',
                    'about_me', 'gender_status', 'create_profile_for', 'marital_status',
                    'height', 'weight', 'body_type', 'complexion',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', None)
        last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name', None)
        user_inst_fields = {}
        if first_name:
            user_inst_fields['first_name'] = first_name
        if last_name:
            user_inst_fields['last_name'] = last_name
        if user_inst_fields:
            User.objects.update_or_create(id=instance.user.id, defaults=user_inst_fields)
        profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(token=instance.token, defaults=validated_data)
        print('profile', profile, created)
        return profile
```

Now , DRF will fetch `first_name` , `last_name` and `email` from the `user` relation on the Profile model.

Comment: But why the fields are not populated with the current value which you can see in the screenshot?

Comment: validated_data.pop('first_name', None) gives me None all the time.

Comment: should my update be in UserSerializer or ProfileSerializer?

Comment: @Apprentice you havent declared those fields in the ProfileSerializer , so it wont display them. And when you added the user field, it is rendered as a select box because it is ForeignKey/OneToOne relation.

Comment: Try the changes i recommended in the answer. The fields will be rendered and values will be updated on form submit.

Comment: how can i populate current data in the form field? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736320/profile-form-not-populated-with-current-value?noredirect=1#comment74516379_43736320

Comment: i'm talking about the form you have in the screenshot.

Comment: I am asking for your help for another question

Comment: Post a separate question with proper context. Would be able to help better :)

Comment: Here is the separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736320/profile-form-not-populated-with-current-value?noredirect=1#comment74516379_43736320 .

Answer (score -1):

My solution for this problem, because solution from this topic return error.

```
class DirectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    first_name=serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', ...)
    last_name=serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name',  ...)

    class Meta:
        model= Director
        fields=['user','first_name', 'last_name',
                'description','private_info']
    

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user', None)
        first_name = user_data.get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
        last_name = user_data.get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)
        
        user_def={
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
        }
        User.objects.update_or_create(id=instance.user.id, defaults=user_def)

        description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        private_info = validated_data.get('private_info', instance.private_info)

        director_def={
            'description': description,
            'private_info': private_info,
        }
        director, created = Director.objects.update_or_create(user=instance.user, 
                                                  defaults=director_def)
        return director

        # Or method in more direct way:
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            user_data = validated_data.pop('user', None)
            first_name = user_data.get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
            last_name = user_data.get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)

            instance.user.first_name = first_name
            instance.user.last_name = last_name
            instance.user.save()

            instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
            instance.private_info = validated_data.get('private_info', instance.private_info)
            instance.save()

            return instance
```

Comment: What did you change? Don't make us mentally diff this against the code in the question. Please read [answer].

Comment: I used  solution above to my  project and get error, so i placed my solution for another person to read and understand. Im sorry if it is confusing.